# Get droplet path without making app document based

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a fairly straightforward question about using droplets for my mac application. My app is not a document based app.

Is there any way to get the path of the item that was dropped? How would I go about implementing this if that was the case? I have looked into this, and it doesn't look like I can do droplets at all without making my app document based, which I really don't want to do.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `NSDocument` at all to make a droplet. Just include `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in your Info.plist (see [Storing Document Types Information in the Application's Property List](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000024-BHADAGHF) for details) and implement `application:openFile:` in your app delegate (there are variants of this method for multiple files etc.).